# Relying on multiple asynchronous resources in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, asynchronous

I have a class which requires two sockets (which I made by subclassing `net.Socket`). I made a class that relies on them both being connected.

```
let net = Npm.require('net');
let EventEmitter = Npm.require('events').EventEmitter;

class Cylon extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(host, port) {
    this._commands = new Cylon.Socket('commands', host, port);  // read async messages through this one.
    this._messages = new Cylon.Socket('messages', host, port);  // send commands through this socket
  }

  execute(command) {
    this._commands.write(`XQ #${command}`);
  }
}
```

Because I rely on both of these, I have a somewhat odd problem of managing the asynchronous events. I tried using the event emitter to do something like this.

```
this._commands.on('connect', () => {
  this._messages.on('connect', () => {
    this.emit('connect', {
      messages: this._messages,
      commands: this._commands
    });
  });
});
```

My tests seem to think it works.

```
Tinytest.addAsync('When connect event happens, all sockets should be connected', function (test, next) {
  let cylon = new Cylon();
  cylon.on('connect', (sockets) => {
    test.isTrue(cylon.messages.connected);
    test.isTrue(cylon.commands.connected);
    next();
  });
});
```

Does this method work for relying on asynchronous resources? Is there a better method?